# How to make a secuence that simulates a text-editor and apply changes on the fly

Tags: javascript, css, real-time

some time ago I saw a website which simulates a text editor and its appeareance was chaning along the way.
The page started simple just like Windows notepad and it was changing little by little. The terminal showed commentaries, css properties and they were applied gradually.

Example:

Hello everyone, I will change the font

```
font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
```

(And you apply the font)

Now lets increase the size

```
font-size:16px;
```

(And the size changes)

It would be something like this terminal displayed in http://www.sublimetext.com/ but applying changes along the way.

I wanted to learn how to make it since I saw it, this guy finished with a really impressive website. Now I have free time and I would like to do something like that. Where should I start ?

Comment: Like this? http://strml.net/

Comment: You must use combination of HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript

Comment: haha love you CD.. God bless you, that was the website.

Comment: http://strml.net/ This is the Web!